# Fill color in Rectangle canvas based on input (Percentage value)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on creating HTML5 canvas object(Rectangle) and fill color based on the value entering in the textbox (validating to enter only percentage value).

I found a link from stack overflow

Here is the code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#my_input").keypress(function(event) {
            // Allow only backspace and delete
            if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37) {
                $("#myCanvas").animate({ opacity: 0.25 });
            }
            else {
                // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
                if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                    event.preventDefault(); 
                }   
            }
        });
    });
```

and here is the code for rectangle

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
          var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

          context.beginPath();
          context.rect(188, 50, 200, 100);
          context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
          context.fill();
          context.lineWidth = 7;
          context.strokeStyle = 'black';
          context.stroke();
```

and here is my html code

```
Numberic Value <input type ="textbox" id="my_input" class="numeric" name="Enter Value" placeholder="Enter value"/>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

What exactly I want When I enter the value 10% in the text box the color has to fill only for that percentage like wise till 100%

Here I am trying with animate opacity 0.25

If I enter any value in the text box i am getting the result for the canvas is reducing 0.25%

Kindly help me for this solution

Thanks in Advance

Ref : [Fill color](http://jsfiddle.net/simonsarris/pby9r/)

Similar to the above link i want the solution when I enter the number in the text box

Comment: Guys kindly help me for the above question to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var perc = 0.1;
var maxWidth = 200;
var maxHeight = 100;

   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#my_input").keyup(function(event) {
        // Allow only backspace and delete
        if ( event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37) {
            //$("#myCanvas").animate({ opacity: 0.25 });
        }
        else {
            // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
            }   
        }
        perc =  Number.parseInt($("#my_input").val()) / 100 ;
        draw();
    });

        function draw(){
            // clear
            context.clearRect(0, 0, 1000, 1000);

            var x = 188;
            var y = 50;

            // outline
            context.beginPath();
            context.rect(x, y, maxWidth, maxHeight);
            context.lineWidth = 7;
            context.strokeStyle = 'black';
            context.stroke();

            // fill
            context.beginPath();
            context.fillStyle = 'yellow';
            context.rect(x, y, maxWidth * perc, maxHeight);
            context.fill();
        }
        draw();
    });
```

Comment: hi @rob thanks for sharing the above code but when i try adding the above code i am getting error call method getContext of null

Comment: hi @rob i solved the above error but now i am getting the below errorUncaught TypeError: Object function Number() { [native code] } has no method 'parseInt' can you please help me out solve this

Comment: Try parseInt($("#my_input").val()) or Number($("#my_input").val()) instead

Comment: hi @rob thank you so much i have put parseInt it was working fine Thanks for sharing your solution for the code